# LiveSASS failed to start

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've been trying to use liveSass in Google Chrome but getting stuck

```
LiveSASS failed to start: http://../screen.css.map
SourceMap is misaligned: color != #fff
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem using _Zurb Foundation 5.x SCSS_. Chrome hints about the line in error in one of my SCSS files. What does your console log say?

Comment: Apparently [it's a bug in Chrome DevTools](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=687233&q=livesass&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Comment: Yes, they flagged as an issue, it's my own topic I opened it;

Comment: Using Canary while waiting stable release to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiveSASS experiment has been removed from DevTools

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=782935

Answer (score 2):

Apparently really it's a bug in Chrome DevTools, but do you can disable **LIVE SASS** in chromeDevTool.

- press **F12**
- press **F1**
- enter in Experiments
- just uncheck **Live SASS**

It's work for me ;)

Comment: Sure, but I'm trying to use LIVE SASS not to disable it.